# PostBuild runs always even when all is up to date

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build

I have a VisualStudio 2010 solution containing a lot of C++ projects (above 100). 
Many of them with some lines in the PostBuild Event (file copying and more).
The problem occurs when building the solution on our build machine using a tfs build definition:

Even if a project is up to date, the post build executes, and a line with "Creating ".unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified" is written to the log file. This increases the build time quite a lot and makes Continous Integration build difficult.
This PostBuild is not triggered when running from VisualStudio.

To narrow down the problem (and exclude any possible problem with reference to unexistent files and so on), I created a new solution file, and added a new C++ console application project to the solution using the VisualStudio project wizard. The only thing I changed from default was this line in the PostBuild event: echo "PostBuild Output" (just to see in the log file when the PostBuild was triggered).

Then I created a new Build Definition running this solution.
And still the PostBuild is activated even if the project is up to date. The same problem happens if I build the solution file running msbuild in a command window. But building from VisualStudio works perfect.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to avoid this PostBuild when the project is 'up to date'?
(I have checked that Linker OutputPath matches the $(TargetPath) setting when building on the build machine.)

Comment: Don't know if it will help you, but this link could be relevant: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653744/msbuild-vc-postbuild-event-runs-even-if-target-is-uptodate

Comment: Yes, I think that could be the answer. I will try to use Custom Builds instead of PostBuild. Thanks.